# Move directory to another partition

Tags: partition

I would like to move the directory `/var/lib/docker` to partition `dev/sda1`

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on

/dev/sda1       338G   11G  314G   4% /
/dev/sdb        295G  180G  101G  65% /var/lib/docker
```

```
fdisk -l /dev/sda

Device      Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1  528384 720003038 719474655   340G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda14   2048      4095      2048     1M BIOS boot
/dev/sda15   4096    528383    524288   256M EFI System
```

I would like to create `/dev/sda2` with 250G storage and mount `/var/lib/docker` to /dev/sda2 but this is wrong way. How do I do this properly?

Comment: You can't move a file or directory to another partition. But you can move a file/directory to a filesystem in another partition. In practical terms, that means you don't move the file/directory to `/dev/sda1`, you move it to the mounted filesystem that resides in `/dev/sda1`. In your case that's `/`.

Comment: Reading on, it seems you don't want to move the directory to `/` at all, but actually you want to move it to a new filesystem at the same mounting but from `/dev/sda2`

Comment: @roaima I can't create `/dev/sda2` with 200GB because I get value out of range. I would like to shrink `/dev/sda1` and create `/dev/sda2` but I can't umount `/dev/sda1` because this is root partition and target is busy.

Comment: You'll need to boot from a rescue system. Then you'll be able to shrink the root filesystem and then the sda1 partition. Then you'll be able to create your sda2 partition, add a filesystem, and mount it. Then copy the data and fix up /etc/fstab